# Tower of Hanoi Java recursion

Tags: java

Hi I was asked to write a tower of hanoi program for my first project I have no experience and really want to learn but don't understand how to even start it and how does recursion even work. I need to comment my work so my teacher understands that I understand but I would like to know how it all works or somewhere I can learn it also what to run Java programs on

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/TheTowersofHanoi.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recursive Algorithm**

The recursive solution to move n discs from the start pole to the end pole using an auxiliary pole is given below.

**Base Case - When n = 1**

Move the disc from start pole to end pole

**Recursive Case - When n > 1**

1. Move (n-1) discs from start pole to auxiliary pole.
2. Move the last disc from start pole to end pole.
3. Move the (n-1) discs from auxiliary pole to end pole.

Stepr  1 and 3 are recursive invocations of the same procedure.

Here is a good [start point](http://www.javawithus.com/programs/towers-of-hanoi)

[image]